# django not accessible from another computer

Tags: python-3.x, django

followed instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/) to create my first django web sever. Haven't done any major customization yet, except.

Setup settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.111', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Started django from cmd prompt

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

All the three url link works on this local machine where django is installed:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/, http://localhost:8080/, http://192.168.1.111:8080/

I then went onto Windows Firewall settings to include 8080 as an inbound rule:
[image]

My problem is http://192.168.1.111:8080/ does throw an exception when accessed from another computer (in the same network, IP being 192.168.1.77). Error is "Site cannot be reached, took too long to respond".

I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong. I am certain its a firewall issue. Turned off windows firewall on 192.168.1.111 and it worked from 192.168.1.77. Question still remains - How do I make it work with firewall on on 192.168.1.111.
My python version is 3.9 and django version is 3.2. FYI - I moved to 8080 just for kicks. I had same issue with 8000.

Two things worth noticing:

(1) 192.168.1.111:8080 does throw a "Not secure connection" warning on the primary machine (where django is installed)

[image]

(2) netstat seems OK too:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -ab

Active Connections

  .
  .
 [postgres.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           DEVSERVER:0            LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           DEVSERVER:0            LISTENING
 [python3.9.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          DEVSERVER:0            LISTENING
  .
  .
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    192.168.1.111:8080     DEVSERVER:50515        ESTABLISHED
 [python3.9.exe]
  TCP    192.168.1.111:49800    52.226.139.121:https   ESTABLISHED
 [SearchApp.exe]
  TCP    192.168.1.111:50502    52.182.141.63:https    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.111:50515    DEVSERVER:8080         ESTABLISHED
  .
  .
C:\Windows\system32>
```

192.168.1.111:8080 just doesn't seem to work from any computer within the network. Tried from 192.168.1.77 (windows/chrome) and 192.168.1.75(windows/firefox)

Comment: Oh yes, and I have looked into other stackoverflow suggestions. Almost all talk about "ALLOWED_HOSTS" and "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080". I couldn't find too much help on firewall issues (which is what I think my issue is)

Comment: Can you ping 111 from 77? Try adding `192.168.1.77` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Comment: @bdbd - Yes, they both are able to ping each other. Adding 192.168.1.77 to ALLOWED_HOSTS doesn't make sense, but I just tried, and it didn't work

Comment: Oh, and I did try both http://... and https://...

Answer (score 1):

OK.. so it was a firewall issue. Apparently, there was another outbound rule with python.exe that was override=True and blocking Public or Private UDP or TCP. I don't even remember. I just deleted all TCP rule relating to python and just kept one (noted in my question above). Its working now